# How to send string result as attachment in stored procedure sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

i need to send a attachment to user, so i found query as attachment is possible but , my requirement is to send the SP result @V_Message variable as attachment within @attach_query_result_as_file , can any one help me in this issue

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation points and cannot leave comments, hence it is here:

If all you need to send an email with well-formed attachments, then you should look into

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'whateverDefaultMailProfile',
@recipients = 'user@domain.com',
@subject = 'Email from SQL Server',
@body = 'Enter text here or use a @text var for body.',
@query= 'exec your_stored_procedure'
@file_attachments = 'C:\filename.ext'
```

your_stored_procedure should dump the output to c:\filename.ext file. You can attach multiple files to multiple recipients from within a single invocation of sp_send_dbmail. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can send attachment via email using  (sp_send_dbmail stored proc)

Refer Example below. Hope this helps

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients='dev@null.com',
@subject=@SUB,
@body=@BODY,

@query= 'SELECT [MID],[HID],[MeC],[LC],[RowCDate]
FROM [JBC].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE RowCDate >= GETDATE()
',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
@query_result_separator = ','
```